# How to load an OpencvSharp.CpPlusPlus.Mat from a XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, opencv

I'm trying to do stereo vision of opencvsharp in C#. I already have distortion matrix stored in a xml file. Now i want to read that matrix to use for calculation. I tried this code:

```
FileStorage fs = new FileStorage();
fs.Open("intrinsics.yml",FileStorageMode.FormatYaml);
Mat M1, M2, D1, D2;
fs["M1"] >> M1;
fs["D1"] >> D1;
fs["M2"] >> M2;
fs["D2"] >> D2;
```

But it's doesn't work. Can someone help me with that? thanks in advance.
P/S: sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 1):

I loaded values for matrices from a XML file by following the examples provided in the OpenCvSharp repository.

This is how I did it:

```
Mat matrix;

using (CvFileStorage fs = new CvFileStorage(xmlfile, null, FileStorageMode.Read))
{
    CvFileNode param = fs.GetFileNodeByName(null, nodeName);
    matrix = new Mat(fs.Read<CvMat>(param));
}
```

Where xmlfile is the path to the XML/YAML file you have (in your case: "intrinsics.yml"), and nodeName is a string with the name of the node your Mat is stored with in the file.

Its worth mentioning that this function loads the objects as CvMat, not Mat, so that's why there is a:

```
new Mat()
```

to convert it to what you need. You can load more values inside the *using* brackets, if you need to recover more data.

For completeness sake, here's how you write values into an XML/YAML file:

```
Mat matrix;
string nodeName = "sample_matrix";

using (CvFileStorage fs = new CvFileStorage(xmlfile, null, FileStorageMode.Write))
{
    fs.Write(nodeName, matrix.ToCvMat());
    fs.StartNextStream();
}
```

You can swap the FileStorageMode.Write to FileStorageMode.Append if you just want to add values to the file and not rewrite it completely.

For reference sake, this is the [sample code file](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/master/sample/CStyleSamplesCS/Samples/FileStorage.cs).